# Summernote 0.8.20 issue seeding with html text - an error occurs on second triggering of the js/jquery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

I am using Summernote 0.8.20 and am trying to populate with seed text depending on the selection of a table field (i.e., the seed text changes depending on the table cell selected). The first time I select a triggering table cell (i.e., one that meets the criteria) it works. The second time the seed text is not displayed and there is a console error:

```
summernote-bs4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
```

The error is caused by the lines:

```
if ($.inArray(currentColumn, assistArray) > -1) {
    $('#ymSpecificLine').summernote('pasteHTML', '<p><b>How were you involved in reviewing?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How did you assist?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How were you involved in planning?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>My role was (what did you do):</b><br><br></p>');
 }else {
     $('#ymSpecificLine').summernote('pasteHTML', '<p><b>How were you involved in reviewing?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How did you lead?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How were you involved in planning?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>My role was (what did you do):</b><br><br></p>');
 }
```

I know this because when I comment them out the error does not occur.

The HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Assist/Lead Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Summernote input area -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id='ymSpecific' class="row">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="ymSpecificLine" class="text-left col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-form-label">You may enter specific information relating to you Assist or Lead:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
                                <textarea class="summernote col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="ymSpecificLine" name="ymSpecificLine" rows="20"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /container -->
                </div><!-- /row -->
            </div><!-- /container -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var leadArray = [8, 16, 24, 32, 44, 52, 60, 68, 80, 81, 82, 83, 91, 92, 93, 94,
                 102, 103, 104, 105, 113, 114, 115, 116];

var assistArray = [7, 15, 23, 31, 42, 43, 50, 51, 58, 59, 66, 67, 77, 78, 79, 88, 89, 90,
             99, 100, 101, 110, 111, 112];

$("#ymSpecificLine").summernote('code', '');
var currentColumn = parseInt(sel.dataset.column, 10);

//Check if Assist or Lead (requires details to be entered)
alert("New currentColumn: " + currentColumn);
if ($.inArray(currentColumn, assistArray) > -1 || $.inArray(currentColumn, leadArray) > -1){

    $('.summernote').summernote({
        toolbar: [
           // [groupName, [list of button]]
           ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
           ['font', ['strikethrough']],
           ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
           ['color', ['color']],
           ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
           ['height', ['height']]
        ]
    });
    
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    
    if ($.inArray(currentColumn, assistArray) > -1) {
        $('#ymSpecificLine').summernote('pasteHTML', '<p><b>How were you involved in reviewing?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How did you assist?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How were you involved in planning?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>My role was (what did you do):</b><br><br></p>');
    }else {
        $('#ymSpecificLine').summernote('pasteHTML', '<p><b>How were you involved in reviewing?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How did you lead?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>How were you involved in planning?</b><br><br></p> <p><b>My role was (what did you do):</b><br><br></p>');
    }
}
```

The result on first select:

[image]

The result on second select:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by commenting out:

```
$("#ymSpecificLine").summernote('code', '');
```

The console error did not occur; however, on each page reload the seed text was duplicated. Which is why that line was there for in the first place. I found:

```
$("#ymSpecificLine").summernote('reset');
```

This does not result in me getting the console message and the seed lines are not duplicated with each reload. However, this also removes the ability to resize the text area.

Is there a way to enable the resize after a reset?

Comment: Hello @Glyn do you know how can I disable the click outside from the summernote dialogs? I want to make the 'X' the only option to close the modal hehe

Comment: @Sophie you can $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})  or  <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    Launch demo modal
 </button> The 'data-keyboard="false"' stops the keyboard 'Esc' from closing the modal.

Comment: Hey Glyn, thank you soo much for your time, I am creating an dialog using the $.extend($.summernote.plugins), specifically using this plugin https://github.com/adeelhussain/summernote-image-attribute-editor I dont know how to insert an ID to the modal which has been creating from jquery ;(

Comment: Summernote creates a dialog, and after I googled it I saw it is different than bootstrap modals

Comment: Ok I did it hahah, with a bad code... but it is working: $("[aria-label='" + lang.imageAttributes.dialogTitle + "']").css('pointer-events', 'none'); 

Thanks alot for your time hehe

Comment: @Sophie Glad it is working for you.